# indecomposable representation of a quiver example

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

Let be

https://i.imgur.com/hufWpv4.jpg

a quiver. We have that $\mathbb{K}Qe_2=span \{e_2,a'',a''' \}$, so $V_1=e_1\mathbb{K}Qe_2=\{0 \}$, $V_2=e_2\mathbb{K}Qe_2=span \{e_2 \}$, $V_3=a''\mathbb{K}Qe_2=span \{a'' \}$,$V_4=a''\mathbb{K}Qe_2=span \{a''' \}$, so a representation  is this:

https://i.imgur.com/OPzfkN7.jpg

and it is indecomposable, right? Moreover, is it non-irreducible?

Comment: Yes and yes.  You can try to classify all of its endomorphism to get that $End_{\mathbb{K}Q}(\mathbb{K}Qe_2) = \mathbb{K}$, which is a local ring and so implies indecomposability.  Or you can also verify more directly by listing out all possible subrepresentations.  More generally, irreducible representations over an acyclic quiver are always 1-dimensional.